# html2pdf error in IE - "Object doesn't support property or method 'setProgress'"

Tags: angular6, jspdf, html2pdf

I am using below code export html into a pdf file using html2pdf in Angular 6 app

```
var element = document.getElementById(elmContainer);

element.style.display = 'block';

html2pdf().from(element).set({
        filename: 'Hello.pdf',
        jsPDF: { orientation: 'portrait', unit: 'in', format: 'a4', compressPDF: false }
    }).outputPdf().then(function () {
        element.style.display = 'none';
    }).save();
```

This is working fine in Chrome but I am getting below error in IE:

> Object doesn't support property or method 'setProgress'

Can any one please help me with this?